# GAE Yaml handler to use URLS

Tags: google-app-engine

I have configured a bucket and to access the files uploaded here what should be the Yaml handler statement?
For example: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/yii2assets/e896c38e/css/bootstrap.css

When I browse this CSS file it prompts to download and looks it doesn’t understand the MIME type.
I can’t provide a static directory since it’s hosted on Google Storage and to access I need to use the URL mentioned above.
Please let me if you have any  IDEAS.
What I need is a handle like:

- url: bootstrap.css
  script    : `URL FROM where TO SERVER`

Like if I have to use a JQuery CDN URL.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can upload static file with your code then config Yaml with static_files please see in [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers).
2. If you want to upload file to Google Storage you can access by sending parameter from python to html file. It depend how you implement it Java, Python have a difference way to implement this.

Comment: I am using PHP engine with GAE and one of my scripts creates a runtime CSS file on the cloud storage for which I have provided the URL in the above post. This CSS file when created on fly fails to serve normally and prompts for download when accessed from browser. 

Do I need to set the content file during creation? But please not it could be any content type image, css and js.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have a few option here

1. provide CSS file as a link by writing the code to access to content in the file as you work for other url in your application.

2. keep your content as text then add them to html page through template API